# Intermittant Error with Git on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone have any idea what would get rid of this error:

> Started by an SCM change
>   [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
>   Building remotely on usmvvwdev70 (windows dotnet) in workspace http://usmawsoab.infor.com:8080/ci/job/Soho%20Controls%20Xi/ws/
>   FATAL: argument type mismatch
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:275)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:256)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:215)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>       at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
>       at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:58)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>       at ......remote call to usmvvwdev70(Native Method)
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:173)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.addCredentials(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl.addCredentials(RemoteGitImpl.java:203)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:662)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:638)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:978)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:488)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1257)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

I'm running 1.5.X Jenkins with the latest git plugins. The error seems to be something about git.

What does resolve it is rebooting the windows machine.... For a while and then after 2 or 3 more builds every build will error out with this again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you found the source of the problem?